# How to deal with different state space size in reinforcement learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm working in **A2C** reinforcement learning where my environment has an increasing and decreasing in the number of agents. As a result of the increasing and decreasing the number of agents, the state space will also change.  I have tried to solve the problem of changing the state space this way:

- If the state space exceeds the maximum state space that selected
  as `n_input`, the excess state space will be selected by
  `np.random.choice` where random choice provides a way of creating random samples from the state space after converting the state space into probabilities.
- If the state space is less than the maximum state I padded the state
  space with zeros.

  ```
  def get_state_new(state):
   n_features =  n_input-len(get_state(env))
   # print("state",len(get_state(env)))
   p = np.array(state)
   p = np.exp(p)
   if p.sum() != 1.0:
       p = p * (1. / p.sum())
   if len(get_state(env)) > n_input:
       statappend = np.random.choice(state, size=n_input, p=p)
       # print(statappend)
   else:
       statappend = np.zeros(n_input)
       statappend[:state.shape[0]] = state
   return statappend
  ```

It works but the results are not as expected and I don't know if this correct or not.

**My question**

Are there any reference papers that deal with such a problem and how to deal with the changing of state space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem using different  solutions  but I found that the encoding is the best solution  for my problem

- Select the model with pre-estimate maximum state space and If the
  state space is less than the maximum  state, we  padded the state
  space  with zeros
- Consider only the state of the agents itself without any sharing of
  the other state.
- As the paper `[1]`  mentioned that the extra connected autonomous
  vehicles (CAVs) are not included in the state and if they are less
  than the max CAVs,  the state is padded with zeros. We can select how
  many agents that we can share their state adding to the agent’s
  state.
- **Encode the state** where it will help us to process the input and compress the information into a fixed length.  In the encoder, every
  cell in the LSTM layer or RNN with Gated Recurrent Units (GRU)
  returns a hidden state (Ht) and cell state (E’t).

[image]

For the encoder, I use the [Neural machine translation with attention code](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention)

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.batch_sz = batch_sz
    self.enc_units = enc_units
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.enc_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')

  def call(self, x, hidden):
    x = self.embedding(x)
    output, state = self.gru(x, initial_state = hidden)
    return output, state

  def initialize_hidden_state(self):
    return tf.zeros((self.batch_sz, self.enc_units))
```

- **LSTM zero paddings and mask** where we pad the state with a special value to be masked (skipped) later. If we pad without masking, the
  padded value will be regarded as actual value, thus, it becomes noise
  in the state [2-4].

1- Vinitsky, E., Kreidieh, A., Le Flem, L., Kheterpal, N., Jang, K., Wu, C., ... & Bayen, A. M. (2018, October). Benchmarks for reinforcement learning in mixed-autonomy traffic. In Conference on Robot Learning (pp. 399-409)

2- Kochkina, E., Liakata, M., & Augenstein, I. (2017). Turing at semeval-2017 task 8: Sequential approach to rumour stance classification with branch-lstm. arXiv preprint arXiv:1704.07221.

3- Ma, L., & Liang, L. (2020). Enhance CNN Robustness Against Noises for Classification of 12-Lead ECG with Variable Length. arXiv preprint arXiv:2008.03609.

4- [How to feed LSTM with different input array sizes?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/48814)

5- Zhao, X., Xia, L., Zhang, L., Ding, Z., Yin, D., & Tang, J. (2018, September). Deep reinforcement learning for page-wise recommendations. In Proceedings of the 12th ACM Conference on Recommender Systems (pp. 95-103).

Answer (score 3):

For the paper, I'm gonna give the same reference as in the [other post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/23315/37982) already:
[Benchmarks for reinforcement learning minmixed-autonomy traffic](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v87/vinitsky18a/vinitsky18a.pdf).

In this approach, indeed, an *expected number of agents* (which are expected to be present in the simulation at any moment in time) is predetermined. During runtime, observations of agents present in the simulation are then retrieved and squashed into a container (tensor) of fixed size (let's call it *overall observation container*), which can contain as many observations (from individual agents) as there are agents expected to be present at any moment in time in the simulation. Just to be clear: `size(overall observation container) = expected number of agents * individual observation size`. Since the actual number of agents present in a simulation may vary from time step to time step, the following applies:

- If less agents than expected are present in the environment, and hence there are less observations provided than would fit into the overall observation container, then zero-padding is used to fill empty observation slots.
- If the number of agents exceeds the expected number of agents, then only a subset of the observations provided will be used. So, only from a randomly selected subset of the available agents the observations are put into the overall observation container of fixed size. Only for the chosen agents, the controller will compute actions to be performed, while "excess agents" will have to be treated as non-controlled agents in the simulation.

Coming back to your sample code, there are a few things I would do differently.

First, I was wondering why you have both the variable `state` (passed to the function `get_state_new`) and the call `get_state(env)`, since I would expect the information returned by `get_state(env)` to be the same as stored already in the variable `state`. As a tip, it would make the code a bit nicer to read if you could try to use the `state` variable only (if the variable and the function call indeed provide the same information).

The second thing I would do differently is how you process states: `p = np.exp(p)`, `p = p * (1. / p.sum())`. This normalizes the overall observation container by the sum of all exponentiated values present in all individual observations. In contrast, I would normalize each individual observation in isolation.

This has the following reason: If you provide a small number of observations, then the sum of exponentiated values contained in all individual observations can be expected to be smaller than when taking the sum over the exponentiated values contained in a larger amount of individual observations. These differences in the sum, which is then used for normalization, will result in different magnitudes of the normalized values (as a function of the number of individual observations, roughly speaking). Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np

# Less state representations
state = np.array([1,1,1])
state = state/state.sum()
state
# Output: array([0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333])

# More state representations
state = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
state = state/state.sum()
state
# Output: array([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
```

Actually, the same input state representation, as obtained by an individual agent, shall always result in the same output state representation after normalization, regardless of the number of agents currently present in the simulation. So, please make sure to normalize all observations on their own. I'll give an example below.

Also, please make sure to keep track of which agents' observations (and in which order) have been squashed into your variable `statappend`. This is important for the following reason.

If there are agents `A1` through `A5`, but the overall observation container can take only three observations, three out of five state representations are going to be selected at random. Say the observations randomly selected to be squashed into the overall observation container stem from from the following agents in the following order: `A2, A5, A1`. Then, these agents' observations will be squashed into the overall observation container in exactly this order. First the observation of `A2`, then that of `A5`, and eventually that of `A1`. Correspondingly, given the aforementioned overall observation container, the three actions predicted by your Reinforcement Learning controller will correspond to agents `A2`, `A5`, and `A1` (in order!), respectively. In other words, the order of the agents on the input side also dictates to which agents the predicted actions correspond on the output side.

I would propose something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

def get_overall_observation(observations, expected_observations=5):
    # Return value:
    #   order_agents: The returned observations stem from this ordered set of agents (in sequence)

    # Get some info
    n_observations = observations.shape[0]  # Actual nr of observations
    observation_size = list(observations.shape[1:])  # Shape of an agent's individual observation

    # Normalitze individual observations
    for i in range(n_observations):
        # TODO: handle possible 0-divisions
        observations[i,:] = observations[i,:] / observations[i,:].max()

    if n_observations == expected_observations:
        # Return (normalized) observations as they are & sequence of agents in order (i.e. no randomization)
        order_agents = np.arange(n_observations)
        return observations, order_agents
    if n_observations < expected_observations:
        # Return padded observations as they are & padded sequence of agents in order (i.e. no randomization)
        padded_observations = np.zeros([expected_observations]+observation_size)
        padded_observations[0:n_observations,:] = observations
        order_agents = list(range(n_observations))+[-1]*(expected_observations-n_observations) # -1 == agent absent
        return padded_observations, order_agents
    if n_observations > expected_observations:
        # Return random selection of observations in random order
        order_agents = np.random.choice(range(n_observations), size=expected_observations, replace=False)
        selected_observations = np.zeros([expected_observations] + observation_size)
        for i_selected, i_given_observations in enumerate(order_agents):
            selected_observations[i_selected,:] = observations[i_given_observations,:]
        return selected_observations, order_agents


# Example usage
n_observations = 5      # Number of actual observations
width = height =  2     # Observation dimension
state = np.random.random(size=[n_observations,height,width])  # Random state
print(state)
print(get_overall_observation(state))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and as I told you that the problem is padding with zero for the state that is small and choosing the maximums expected agents. I can solve the problem using the encode and decode by selecting the maximums as the maximum number of agents expected but I will be padding small state with zeros. Also, I used normalization to remove negative probabilities.

Comment: See what is the difference between your code and my code 
http://tpcg.io/YBlOAbH8

Comment: The paper mentioned that the extra CAVs are not included in the state and it doesn't generate it randomly.

Comment: Please observe the difference of inputs our codes apparently expect. In the link you provided above, the input is a simple list (cast to an array) which is then fed into the processing pipeline. However, my code snipped expects multidimensionality, so to say. While the 0th dim is reserved for iterating through different agents' observations, each individual observation must be at least of one extra-dimension itself, i.e. an observation cannot be a scalar, but must be at least a scalar nested in a list: `state =[[0.19436307], [0.22327741], [0.35353937], [1.], [0.], [1.]]`.

Comment: Also, I added a TODO in the code snipped above, since the code may still perform 0-divisions. The simplest way to avoid this would of course be to not divide in case of `observations[i,:].max()` being `0`. However, since it might also be possible that states include negative values, which might still be supposed to be divided by some value, proper 0-division-handling is a design choice on its own, such that I only provided a TODO in the code above.

Comment: Where do you get negative probabilities? The only place where that may happen is at the output nodes of your RL algo. But there, you could simply squash all probabilities belonging to a single agent (to be controlled) through a softmax function, which will take care of making probabilities positive.

Comment: Concerning the paper. Yes, as stated above, excess agents are not controlled by the RL algo (as long as more agents are present than can be handled by the controller). Concerning the state creation: Look at section 3.2. The paper doesn't specify the order in which agents' observations are fitted into the overall observation/state representation. But since it ultimately shall not matter which agent is handled where in the controller, there shall be no harm incurred by fitting randomly selected agents into the state representation in random order. Just because of the absence of a natural order.

Comment: The negative probabilities will be in `np.random.choice`.

Comment: Where do probabilities come into play? Consider the following line: `np.random.choice(range(n_observations), size=expected_observations, replace=False)`. Let's suppose, `n_observations = 5` and `expected_observations = 4`. Then, `range` will create an object similar to a list which would contain the following values: `[0,1,2,3,4]`. Then, `np.random.choice` will take as many *unique* (because `replace=False`) samples  from `[0,1,2,3,4]` as have been specified by parameter `size`. So, if `size=4`, then a random  sample from `[0,1,2,3,4]` might look like `[4, 2, 0, 1]` or `[1, 2, 0, 3]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221100/discussion-between-i-thamary-and-daniel-b).